# C# checkbox return invalid value

Tags: c#, checkbox

I having below code but I don't understand why when I check the check box , the access string is not change to "Y".

```
string access1 = "N";`

void checkvalue(CheckBox chkbox, string access)
{
    if (chkbox.Checked)
    {
        access = "Y";
    }
    else
    {
        access = "N";
    }
}

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkvalue(checkBox1, access1);
}
```

Comment: Remove the parameter you are passing or declare it a `ref string access` (`checkvalue(checkBox1, ref access1)`).

Comment: Just update `access1` directly instead of passing it in as a parameter.

Comment: If what you want is to know whether to use Y or N you don't need a variable, just ask for `chkbox.Checked`.

Comment: you should make `checkValue` return a bool or an enum (or the string "N" or "Y" if you must)

Comment: Thank you very much, it  work like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `access` parameter of your `checkvalue` method is not being passed by reference (using the `ref` keyword.)  So, you are setting `access` locally to "N" and immediately forgetting about it as soon as your `checkvalue` method returns.  The `access1` variable is unaffected.  Your method needs to accept `access` by reference using the `ref` keyword.

Comment: the immutable comment is not helpful since its irrelevant in this context, he is reassigning a string (or trying to) not changing the value of a string

Comment: @pm100 the OP is under the impression that he is assigning a value to the string the way he would be assigning a value to an `int`.  But in any case, technically you are right, so I fixed that.